# undesired multiple matches creating links with regex matches in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am creating a link out of certain characters that match my regex, and all works as expected as long as a specific match does not appear more than once in the input string.

I want to find any instance of "RTR-" or "RO-" followed by 2 to 4 numbers, and convert that to a link. ex. "This is RTR-1234" becomes

`"This is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a>"`

I pass my string to:

```
Function linkifyText(ByVal txt As String) As String

    Dim regx As New Regex("\b(RTR-|RO-)\d{2,4}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    Dim mactches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(txt)

    For Each match As Match In mactches
        txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='http://server/browse/" & match.Value & "'>" & match.Value & "</a>")
    Next

    Return txt
End Function
```

This seems to work fine, even when there are multiple differing matches.  For exmaple "This is RTR-1234, and this is RTR-4321" becomes

`This is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a> and this is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-4321'>RTR-4321</a>`

I run into problems however, when the same match occurs more than once in the input string.  For example, "This is RTR-1234 again this is RTR-1234" becomes

`This is <a href='http://server/browse/<a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a>'><a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a></a> again this is <a href='http://server/browse/<a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a>'><a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

Why not just do this in one search and replace operation?

```regex
\b((?:R(?:TR|O))-[0-9]{2,4})\b
```

**Replace With:** `<a href='http://server/browse/$1'>$1</a>`
[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find any instance of `RTR-` or `RO-` followed by 2 to 4 numbers

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qD4kC4/1

**Sample text**

```
I want to find any instance of "RTR-" or "RO-" followed by 2 to 4 numbers, and convert that to a link. 

ex. "This is RTR-1234" 

For example, "This is RTR-1234 again this is RTR-1234" becomes
```

**After Replacement**

```
I want to find any instance of "RTR-" or "RO-" followed by 2 to 4 numbers, and convert that to a link. 

ex. "This is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a>" 

For example, "This is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a> again this is <a href='http://server/browse/RTR-1234'>RTR-1234</a>" becomes
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      R                        'R'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        TR                       'TR'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        O                        'O'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2,4}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 2
                             and 4 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation, I've got a much better understanding of what's going on, problem solved!